# R markdown::render not printing multiple kableExtra objects returned by a function

Tags: r, printing, markdown, render, kableextra

My problem is as follows. Say I have a `content.Rmd` file in which I want to call a function (**f** below) returning a list containing **two** kable objects (with kablExtra styling features). My goal is to render `content.Rmd` from an external script (`master_file.R`). For comparison, I also included `g` function which returns only one kable object. See below the content of files and results.

`content.Rmd` content:

````
    ```{r}

library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
df1 <- mtcars[1:5, 1:5]
df2 <- iris[1:5,]

f <- function(){
k1 <- df1 %>%
    kable() %>%
    kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), full_width=F)
k2 <- df2 %>%
    kable() %>%
    kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), full_width=F)
return(list(k1, k2))
}

g <- function(){
k1 <- df1 %>%
    kable() %>%
    kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), full_width=F)
return(k1)
}
f()
g()
    ```
````

`master_file.R` content:

```
library(rmarkdown)
render('content.Rmd')
```

[Result][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/21lyk.png

As you can see, only the `g` function prints correctly output (btw., both `f` and `g` print correctly after clicking 'knit' button within RStudio).
It is really crucial in my application to make `f` printing multiple objects from one function call when rendering .Rmd from an external R script. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

In an RMarkdown document, printing needs to be handled specially depending on the class of the object.  Putting those two tables in a list hid their class.  This will fix it:  instead of using

```
list(k1, k2)
```

use

```
htmltools::tagList(htmltools::HTML(k1), htmltools::HTML(k2))
```